# How to multiply vertices with model matrix outside the vertex shader

Tags: c++, opengl-es

I am using OpenGL ES2 to render a fairly large number of mostly 2d items and so far I have gotten away by sending a premultiplied model/view/projection matrix to the vertex shader as a uniform and then multiplying my vertices with the resulting MVP in there.

All items are batched using texture atlases and I use one MVP per batch. So all my vertices are relative to the translation of that MVP.

Now I want to have rotation and scaling for each of the separate items, which means I need a different model for each of them. So I modified my vertex to include the model (16 floats!) and added a mat4 attribute in my shader and it all works well. But I'm kinda dissapointed with this solution since it dramatically increased the vertex size.

So as I was staring at my screen trying to think of a different solution I thought about transforming my vertices to world space before I send them over to the shader. Or even to screen space if its possible. The vertices I use are unnormalized coordinates in pixels.

So the question is, is such a thing possible? And if yes how do you do it? I can't think why it shouldn't be since its just maths but after a fairly long search on google, it doesn't look like a lot of people are actually doing this...

Strange cause if it is indeed possible, it would be quite a major optimization in cases like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of matrices per batch are limited then you can pass all those matrices as uniforms (preferably in a UBO) and expand the vertex data with an index which specifies which matrix you need to use.

This is similar to GPU skinning used for [skeletal animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeletal_animation).

Comment: You can still pass multiple matrices in the regular uniforms. You will just be limited in how many you can pass.

Comment: Nice thanks rachet. I've seen code where people do that but I was really wondering which solution is actually more efficient. Passing the matrix as an attribute or as a uniform array? Or something else I haven't found?? I tried the attribute solution and it looks sort of OK. I'm just worried about the vertex size cause I might have to add lighting too. I'll try your suggestion tomorrow see how it goes. Would you suggest using glDrawElementsInstanced or maybe pass an index in some other way? The target board is an nvidia k1 by the way.

Comment: Oh and the batch size ranges somewhere between 50-5000 vertices. Although usually its around 500-1000 vertices really. Or even less.